# prove $-1<a+b\le 3$, if $|4ax^3-2bx-a+b|\le 1,\forall x\in [0,1]$

Tags: inequality

if 
$$|4ax^3-2bx-a+b|\le 1,\forall x\in [0,1],a>0$$
show that
$$-1<a+b\le 3$$

**Attempt**

Assmue that $f(x)=4ax^3-2bx-a+b$,then
$$|-a+b|\le 1\Longrightarrow -1\le a-b\le 1$$
and
$$|4a-2b-a+b|\le 1\Longrightarrow -1\le 3a-b\le 1$$
we have
$$a+b=3a-b-2(a-b)\in[-3,3]$$
where some wrong? why? Thank in advance

Comment: Your argument is absolutely right, it's just that your result is weaker than the original claim. You only proved $-3 \le a+b \le 3$ so you still have to prove that $a+b > -1$.

Comment: Btw, the original claim is clearly false since $a=-1,b=-2$ satisfies $|4ax^3-2bx-a+b| \le 1$ but you have $a+b=-3$. So the result you proved ($-3 \le a+b \le 3$) is the best possible result.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got

$$ -1 \le b - a \le 1$$

Notice that $a > 0$ thus $2a > 0$. Adding these up,

$$ -1 < a + b $$

And you've already got

$$ -3 \le a + b \le 3$$

So taking the stricter bounds of the two and we finally have

$$ -1 < a + b \le 3$$